# Android- Google map v2 Draw circle

Tags: android, google-maps

Google, on Feb 26, released `Circle` as an overlay type:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle

But how do I update to the new release of Google Map V2? When will it be available in Android SDK Manager? I have the previous Google Map V2 library within "Google Play Services" (Rev. 5) which does NOT include `Circle` class

Comment: Not related to question, but are there any release notes for this release? Really interested what else they changed with this release

Comment: This library may help - https://github.com/i-schuetz/map_areas

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To **update** Google MAP V2:

Open Android SDK Manager -> Go to Extras -> Check for the update of **Google Play Service**. if it doesn't shows the *update available*, then go to *Packages->Reload*. update the google play service to **Revision 5**.

After that remove the old Google Play Service Library project from Eclipse Workspace. import it again. add this library project in your current project. now u will have the **Circle** class available under *com.google.android.gms.maps.model* package. and you can use that to add circle in your map.

**To Add Circle**:

```
mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
        .center(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
        .radius(100)
        .strokeColor(Color.RED)
        .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

And for your information, this is [Release note for changes of February 2013](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/releases#february_2013).

**EDIT :** This is [Release notes for June 2016.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/releases#june_27_2016) You can now make the circles clickable, which may be helpful if you want to do some action with circle.