# Android Maps API v2 add circle cannot be resolved

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I need to add circle on map, but after update Google Play Services as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129012/android-google-map-v2-draw-circle/15129625#15129625) it still "cannot be resolved"
How to make it work?

Code:

```
     CircleOptions co = new CircleOptions();
        co.center(latlng);
        co.radius(getCircleSize());
        co.fillColor(getCircleColor());
        co.strokeColor(getStrokeColor());
        co.strokeWidth(2.0f);
    Circle circle = mMap.addCircle(co);
```

Error is:

> CircleOptions cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Have you imported the project-library google-play-service-lib correctly ?

Comment: is it? http://gyazo.com/b5d9d21a9b6cce0417827843ab537684.png

Comment: Yep. Just tested it on my code, it works perfectly. Are you sure the imports are correct?

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Circle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CircleOptions;

Comment: no, imports unresolved too: `The import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Circle cannot be resolved`

Comment: Oh. That's definitely not good. Try to follow these steps from the begining https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: Yeah, i forgot — i copied project-lib into workspace from sdk dir. I used not updated copy >_< Now i imported right from sdk dir updated google-play-service and its ok (before i follow to tutorial). Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @VasiliyStepin Please post the resolution as an answer and accept it. Someone somewhere will have the same issue and you can help them ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. If you copy project-lib Google Play Services from SDK directory into your workspace directory, after update by Android SDK Manager don't forget again copy new version library project. My fall :)